# appname.ViewsVC collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am building a collection view and am getting the following error.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[appname.ViewsVC collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Here is the code where i custom cell

```
// cell configuration
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ViewsCell", for: indexPath) as! ViewsCell

    cell.fullnameLbl.text = self.viewsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].capitalizeEachWord

    // pic setup
    avaArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (data:Data?, error:Error?) in
        if error == nil {
            cell.avaImg.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

I created the collection view and the cell in storyboard and have given them the proper identifiers. I also connected the UIimageView and the label to the cell class.

Any ideas what could be wrong.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I realized that I was missing UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate at the top of the View controller

`class ViewsVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {`

Comment: you are an angel

Comment: i haven a controller extends of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, but need an UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDataSource.. only need call o writing these two extensions